# Import .rwz file into Outlook 2011 for Mac?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook

Is it possible to import the .rwz file into Outlook 2011 for Mac so I don't have to rewrite all of my rules?

Answer (score 0):

The `.rwx` file is where mailbox rules were stored in versions of Windows Outlook prior to 2002.  Rules definitions are subsequently stored in a user's `.pst` file.

The Mac version of Outlook uses a different format to store its mailbox rules definitions.

**Short answer, no**, it is not possible.  In fact, it is apparently quite the headache getting into those files at all.

The closest thing I've found has been [this Developer Reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206763.aspx) that discusses the Outlook Rules Object model

Comment: Do you mean `.rwz` ?